# Format data for highcharts solid gauge graph

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts, format

I want the total value for my solid gauge graph to be represented as number with comma. But I am getting the number without any commas. I tried

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        thousandsSep: ','
    }
});
```

But this didnt worked with solid gauge graph.
[image]

I want the big number to be formated.
Please Help.

Answer (score 4):

you need to use `format` option under `dataLabels`

for more details read **[Documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting)**

```js
$(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang: {
            thousandsSep: ','
        }
    });
    var gaugeOptions = {
        chart: {
            type: 'solidgauge'
        },
        title: null,
        pane: {
            center: ['50%', '85%'],
            size: '140%',
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            background: {
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
                innerRadius: '60%',
                outerRadius: '100%',
                shape: 'arc'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        // the value axis
        yAxis: {
            stops: [
                [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
            ],
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorTickInterval: null,
            tickAmount: 2,
            title: {
                y: -70
            },
            labels: {
                y: 16
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            solidgauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    y: 5,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    useHTML: true
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // The speed gauge
    $('#container-speed').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 200000,
            title: {
                text: 'Speed'
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Speed',
            data: [180000],
            dataLabels: {
                format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                    ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{point.y:,.0f}</span><br/>' +
                    '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">km/h</span></div>'
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' km/h'
            }
        }]

    }));

    // The RPM gauge
    $('#container-rpm').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 5,
            title: {
                text: 'RPM'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'RPM',
            data: [1],
            dataLabels: {
                format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                    ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:.1f}</span><br/>' +
                    '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">* 1000 / min</span></div>'
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' revolutions/min'
            }
        }]
    }));

    // Bring life to the dials
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Speed
        var chart = $('#container-speed').highcharts(),
            point,
            newVal,
            inc;

        if (chart) {
            point = chart.series[0].points[0];
            inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100);
            newVal = point.y + inc;
            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
                newVal = point.y - inc;
            }
            point.update(newVal);
        }

        // RPM
        chart = $('#container-rpm').highcharts();
        if (chart) {
            point = chart.series[0].points[0];
            inc = Math.random() - 0.5;
            newVal = point.y + inc;
            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 5) {
                newVal = point.y - inc;
            }
            point.update(newVal);
        }
    }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>

<div style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto">
<div id="container-speed" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
<div id="container-rpm" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Withing the Y-axis configuration.you can make use of the formatter function in order to the formating on solid guage here below is the example.

[image: Solid Gauge Chart Formating on Yaxis]